# SQL Server Inserts during a drop/create table sequence

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

My task is to add columns to a table at a specific position.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.[Tmp_SomeTableName]
(
some schema
)

INSERT INTO dbo.[Tmp_SomeTableName]
(
SELECT [New column order here] from  dbo.[SomeTableName]
)

DROP TABLE dbo.[SomeTableName]

EXECUTE sp_rename N'dbo.[Tmp_SomeTableName]', N'SomeTableName','OBJECT'
```

My question is simple, what will MSSQL do with an

```
INSERT INTO dbo.[SomeTableName]
```

while the table reconstruction is in progress? Will it queue inserts and send them at the end of the reconstruction? Or should I expect sql exceptions (and failure to insert data)?

Note: On average, the table in question is seeing traffic of about 20 inserts per minute. No update queries are run on the table, and <5 select queries per hour

Comment: If this is for homework or R&D fine, but if this is for any software that you intend to use please stop and re-evaluate the way you're solving this problem. Dynamically adding columns to a Sql Server db is wrong on so many levels and there are very few valid use cases for this functionality. Consider adding a new table and store the key in a column and a value in a column so that you can simply add another row to this table rather than modify a table on the fly.

Comment: Column order is just a visual thing. Why do you need to reorder the columns? There's no logical reason that you would need to reorder columns unless you are using `SELECT *` and counting on a column order - that is a very bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

Since the table doesn't exist you will get SQL exceptions. Your SQL scripts/procs have no way of knowing that the table is in 'limbo', as far as they're concerned the table doesn't exist and it's an error.

edit: It's possible to insert against a view, so you could do something along the following:
Create a view against the original table which is used by your scripts/procs for the insert. Then when you need to, create your second table, update the view to point at this second table so the inserts can continue. Then update your original table and point the view back to the original table, and move the data that's been collected in the meantime. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms180800.aspx

Comment: Just edited with a possible workaround, but I'd really be looking to find an alternative solution to the problem. Why is the column order important?

Comment: Because the boss is the boss, thanks for your insight

Comment: I can maybe understand the need to add columns on the fly, but the column order should be irrelevant provided best practices are implemented (i.e. avoiding use of 'SELECT *' , 'INSERT INTO dbo.Table VALUES (1,2,3)'.

If that was the case you could get away with just an alter table statement.

Comment: That said, if your hands are tied the VIEW solution should work, if you can get away with updating your DML statements

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new table on-fly, using

```
select [fields] into new_Table from  old_table [join another_old_table]. . . .
```

This is documented here

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx

This way you can dynamically create whatever columns you need in new table out of old table